Issue with footer layout for big screens
Hi I'm trying to design a footer which consists of 4 buttons of different size 25%,30%,20%,25% for big screens like 22 and 27 inches.Pasting by code below,

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/scanner"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_16dp">

            <!-- CardView 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view_1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:foreground="@drawable/footer"
                android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/card_view_2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_38dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_44dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/tab1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tab1_text"
                        style="@style/footerButtons"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/tab1_txt"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:text="@string/tab1_txt" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- CardView 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view_2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:foreground="@drawable/footer"
                android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/card_view_1"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/card_view_3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_38dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_44dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/tab2"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/tab2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tab2_Text"
                        style="@style/footerButtons"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/tab2_txt"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:text="@string/tab2_txt" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- CardView 3 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view_3"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:foreground="@drawable/footer"
                android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/card_view_2"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/card_view_4"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_45dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_45dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/tab3"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/tab3" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tab3_text"
                        style="@style/footerButtons"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/tab3_txt"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:text="@string/tab3_txt" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <!-- CardView 4 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view_4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:foreground="@drawable/footer"
                android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/card_view_3"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_38dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_44dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/tab4"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/tab4" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tab4_text"
                        style="@style/footerButtons"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/tab4_txt"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:text="@string/tab4_txt" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

I’m stuck how to adjust for big screens.and all resolutions. I don’t want to give any fixed height and width can you help me with this.with the help of constraints I need it

You can create a horizontal chain and use the layout_constraintHorizontal_weight property provided by ConstraintLayout. You can read about it here
So taking your code, simplifying with just two cards, you can do something like this. I have allowed both cards to occupy 50% space, i.e. weight is 1
<!-- CardView 1 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view_1"
                android:layout_width="0dp" // Notice width is zero
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight = "1" // Notice weight is 1 here
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:foreground="@drawable/footer"
                android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/card_view_2" // Creating a chain here
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_38dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_44dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/tab4"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/tab4" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tab4_text"
                        style="@style/footerButtons"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/tab4_txt"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:text="@string/tab4_txt" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<!-- CardView 2 -->
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view_2"
                 android:layout_width="0dp" // Notice width is zero
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight = "1" // Notice weight is 1 here
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80dp"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:foreground="@drawable/footer"
                android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/_0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/card_view_1"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_38dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_44dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_8dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/tab4"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/tab4" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tab4_text"
                        style="@style/footerButtons"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/tab4_txt"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:text="@string/tab4_txt" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


Another alternative, or if you a more advanced use case, you can use a Barrier or Guideline. Also, here is an awesome explanation of when to use which element
